# IFrame Undefined value on body onload

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload, onload-event

How can I get the value of my iframe using body onload, I get an undefined value.

my non-working code:

index.html

```
<body onload ="loadThis()">

      <iframe id = "myframe" src = "sample.html"></iframe>

</body>
```

my.js

```
function loadThis(){

      var doc = window.frames['myframe'].document.getElementById('userID').innerHTML;

      alert(doc);

}
```

The function "loadThis()" runs before the Iframe is loaded. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
<body >

  <iframe onload ="loadThis()" id = "myframe" src = "sample.html"></iframe>

</body>
```

Comment: Haven't thought of that, nice.